# How Refresh Page Automatically

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp, web

How to refresh a page automatically, after pressing the back button in JavaScript? I have tried location.reload but it did not work.

Comment: or to disable back button on web browser n keyboard

Comment: you cannot disable the back button of a browser. Tell me exactly what do  you wanna do here ?

Comment: What about disabling "close browser", "kill process", "shutdown machine" ? :) - not much harder than disabling back button in browser (with about the same result).

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="refreshed" value="no">
<script type="text/javascript">
    onload=function(){
        var e=document.getElementById("refreshed");
        if(e.value=="no") {
            e.value="yes";
        } else {
            e.value="no";location.reload();
        }
     }
</script>
```

Source: http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?137518-How-to-refresh-page-after-clicking-quot-Back-quot-button

Answer (score 0):

You can bind `location.reloade` to [`window.onpopstate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onpopstate) event. Try:

```
 window.onpopstate = function( e ) {
     location.reload();
 }
```

Comment: yeah. it will work but it the implementation has limited support.